# Zookeeper (as dependency for Clickhouse) helm chart migration from AZ to multi AZ with ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, argocd

I'm trying to figure out zookeeper migration.
TLDR: originally we deployed zookeeper with three replicas in one AZ us-eas-1a. We used this public [chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/bc39d28075199d43c20dc4dd6788386e5c84bc77/bitnami/zookeeper/values.yaml#L590).

Now we need to redeploy the zookeeper to multi-AZ: us-eas-1a,us-eas-1b, us-eas-1c. Since each ZK replica has PVC, I need to migrate/restore existing PVC across three AZs.

We have VolumeSnapshot, which I'm trying to use for restoring my new PVC.
But it didn't work because the helm chart deploys the PVCs and I can modify it to add dataSource.

I would highly appreciate any ideas/advice on how to proceed with migration.